# How can I use multiple string formats in C# in a way that I am combining {0:c} and {0:n} in Writeline

Tags: c#

For example is it possible to do

```
WriteLine("Statement : {0:c}", 23455);

WriteLine("Statement : {0:n}", 23455);
```

In one line of code using WriteLine?

Comment: Do you understand that `{0:c}` is just the 0th placeholder?  What happens if you add another with the correct index?  Try it.  Then please read [ask] and take the [tour];  *is it possible...* is not a very good question

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could add what is the result that you expect?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes I understand I'm just attempting to format the 0th placeholder in terms of currency and as a number at the same time within the string.

Comment: @GSazheniuk The result I'm looking for is "Statement : $23,455" by use of a single line of Writeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output in the format `$23,455` you would use `{0:c0}`, the final `0` tells how many decimal places to show, it defaults to `{0:c2}` if you don't specify a number.